# How to get weekly Google Fit Rest API data

Tags: python, google-fit, google-fit-api

I am trying to get my weekly aggregated step count from Google Fit using their REST Api following their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total) but the point data is coming back empty. I have enabled read location and activity scope for the access token. My code :

```
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate"

access_token = ""

headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token),
  "Content-Type": "application/json;encoding=utf-8"
  }

body = {
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": 1438705622000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1439310422000
}


response = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
  }],
```

Your `aggregateBy` specifies both the data type name and data source id; the latter takes precedence, so this will only return data if the `estimated_steps` stream contains data on the server.

I'd suggest removing the `dataSourceId`, then the default data source for `step_count.delta` will be used.

Comment: I am still getting an empty point dictionary after removing **dataSourceId**

Comment: Do you have data in the data source if you just try to read it, without aggregating?

Comment: Yes I do, I use Google Fit daily and I can be able to view my activity data from the app

Comment: OK, but have you managed to issue a request to get that data without aggregation via the REST API?

Comment: I cannot find a google fit's API endpoint to access the unaggregated data for my steps count. Would you please direct me?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get - you can try it in the docs, and then paste the URL here so I can see what you've tried.

Comment: ```https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:HMD Global:Nokia 3.2:b5dc902a:activity_from_steps/datasets/1438705622000-1439310422000 ``` This is the request I've used for dataSource request. The response I get from that url is ```{
  "minStartTimeNs": "1438705622000",
  "maxEndTimeNs": "1439310422000",
  "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:HMD Global:Nokia 3.2:b5dc902a:activity_from_steps",
  "point": []
} ```

Comment: `1438705622000` - note that's in nanos - is Thu 01 Jan 1970 01:23:58 AM BST. Also, that request is for an activity segment data source, not the steps you're asking about.

Comment: (Even in millis, the end time `1439310422000` is Tue 11 Aug 2015 05:27:02 PM BST. That's a while ago. Are you sure you expect data then?)

Comment: Thank You so much I changed the millisecond's body and was able to get the step count data I need. My problem was I used the time provided in Google Fit's documentation.